# Trying breakup group data and sort them according to respective columns

Tags: excel, vba

I'm quite new to VBA. For each group shown below, I am trying to sort this data into a table where I can see if the student has been a part of a certain group or not. I have screenshotted the table where I am starting at, and the the second screenshot shows the table that I am trying to populate. If the student has been in the group or not, I want the table to write "exists" where the student has been a group member of.

Here's where the data that I am starting with.

[image]

Here's the table for which that I am trying to populate:

[image]

Comment: You can do this with a formula, no VBA needed.

Comment: How a student can be twice in the same Group? Should the code solve this case, too?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please, try the next code:

```
Sub extractStudGroups()
 'The code needs a reference to 'Microsoft Scripting Runtime'.
 Dim sh As Worksheet, lastR As Long, arr, arrSt, El, dict As New scripting.Dictionary
 Dim arrGr, arrKey, arr1, arrFin, i As Long, j As Long, k As Long, mtch
 
 Set sh = ActiveSheet 'use here the necessary sheet
 lastR = sh.Range("B" & sh.rows.count).End(xlUp).row  'last row (calculated for colum B:B)
 arr = sh.Range("B4:C" & lastR).value  'put the range to be processed in an array (works faster)
 
 For i = 1 To UBound(arr)                 'iterate between the array rows number:
    arrSt = Split(arr(i, 2), vbLf)           'split the cells content on the line separator
    For Each El In arrSt                     'iterate between the splited array elements:
        If Not dict.Exists(El) Then        'put the array elements in a dictionary (as unique keys)
            dict.Add El, arr(i, 1)            'the item is the value in array col 1 (Group 1, 2, 3...)
        Else
            dict(El) = dict(El) & "|" & arr(i, 1) 'add to the key value the other Groups, separated by "|"
        End If
    Next El
 Next i

 arr1 = Application.Index(arr, 0, 1)   'make a slice of the fist array column
 ReDim arrFin(1 To dict.count + 1, 1 To UBound(arr1) + 2): k = 2 'redim the final array (to keep the processed result)
 arrFin(1, UBound(arr1) + 2) = "Order" 'Create a helper (last) column to sort ascending according to the right number in Student (1, 2, 3...)
 For i = 1 To UBound(arr1)             'put the groups in the array (like headers), starting from the second column
    arrFin(1, i + 1) = arr1(i, 1)
 Next i
 For i = 0 To dict.count - 1           'terate between dictionary keys/items:
    arrFin(k, 1) = dict.Keys(i): arrFin(k, UBound(arr1) + 2) = Right(dict.Keys(i), Len(dict.Keys(i)) - 7) 'dict key in column 1 and numeric part in the last column
    arrSt = Split(dict.items(i), "|")  'split by "|" (extract Group1, 2, 3...) to create an array
    For Each El In arrSt               'iterate betwen groups of a specific student groups:
        mtch = Application.match(El, arr1, 0) 'if the specific group is found in the dictionary item array
        If IsNumeric(mtch) Then arrFin(k, mtch + 1) = "exists" '"exists" is writen in the appropriate column
    Next
    k = k + 1                          'increment the final array row to be filled with data
 Next i
 'drop the final array content at once, sort by last (helper) column and delete the helper column:
 With sh.Range("F2").Resize(UBound(arrFin), UBound(arrFin, 2))
    .value = arrFin
    .Sort Key1:=.cells(1, UBound(arr1) + 2), Order1:=xlAscending, Header:=xlYes
    .cells(1, UBound(arr1) + 2).EntireColumn.Delete
 End With
End Sub
```

I tried commenting the code lines to make it easier to be understood.

Please, send some feedback after testing it.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily do this with a formula:

`=IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(D15,$C$4)), "exists", "not exists")`

In the above formula `SEARCH` will return a number if the text is found, and the `IF` will return "exists". Create a formula for each column and copy it down. You will need to replace `D15` with the real column since you don't show the column/row in you example.